# How does $\mathrm{SL}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ act on some space in the way that $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ acts on the upper half plane in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, geometry, lie-groups

I have yet to figure this out. All I've done is look at some generators and try to see where the connection is to some other space.

Comment: You meant $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts on the upper-half plane $\mathbb{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}, \Im(z) > 0\}$ (it is its group of biholomorphisms). Let $\gamma ={\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}a & b  \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}} \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ then $\gamma \cdot z =\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$.
Let $\lambda ={\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g &h  & j \end{pmatrix}} \in SL_3(\mathbb{R})$ then $\lambda\cdot (z,w) = (\frac{az+bw+c}{ga+hw+jc},\frac{az+bw+c}{ga+hw+jc})$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much for your response. I think you have made a typo though; what happened to $d, e,$ and $f$ in $\lambda \cdot (z, w)$?

Comment: Sure I meant $\lambda\cdot (z,w) = (\frac{az+bw+c}{ga+hw+jc},\frac{dz+ew+f}{ga+hw+jc})$.

Comment: Do you know about symmetric spaces associated with semisimple Lie groups? If not, do you know how $SL(n)$ acts on the space of projective classes of positive definite matrices?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I’m afraid to say my answer is no to both questions.

Answer (score 1):

For any group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ there is a natural action of $G$ on $G/H$ at the most abstract level.  For Lie groups choose $H$ to be a closed subgroup. Or even a special kind of subgroup such as fixed point subgroup of an involution (e.g., orthogonal group will lead to action on the space of symmetric matrices.). You can take #H$ to be the subgroup of upper trianglular matrices then the action is on a projective variety (compact space) of flags etc.

Answer (score 1):

To cut the long story short, the correct generalization of the upper half-plane to the case of the Lie group $G=SL(n, R)$ is the **symmetric space** $P_n$ of $SL(n, R)$. One way to describe it is as the space of projective classes of positive definite quadratic forms in $n$ variables on which $G$ acts via the change of variables. Here two forms $q, q'$ are projectively equivalent iff they are scalar multiples of each other. Equivalently, $P_n$ can be identified with the space of positive definite symmetric $n\times n$ matrices of determinant $1$. The action of $G$ on this space is given by 
$$
(g, M)\mapsto g^T M g, 
$$ 
$g\in G$, $M\in P_n$.

The action of $G$ on $P_n$ is transitive with the stabilizer of $I_n\in P_n$ equal to the orthogonal group $O(n)$. Now, you see the similarity with the action of $PSL(2,R)$ on the open unit disk in the complex plane. There is also a  (unique up to scale) $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $P_n$, at the identity matrix it is given by $\langle A, B\rangle=tr(AB)$, where $A, B$ are symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. This is an analogue of the hyperbolic metric on the unit disk (or the upper half-plane if you prefer). Notice however that the hyperbolic metric has constant negative curvature, while each $G$-invariant metric on $P_n$ has sectional curvature $\le 0$, with some directions of negative curvature and some directions of zero curvature, if $n\ge 3$.

You can read much more for instance in Helgasson's book on symmetric spaces. However, start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) to get an idea of what this staff is about.